# How can I have sent emails copied into a folder in documents?

Tags: mail.app, email

I would like to create a mail rule in apple mail to have sent emails to a particular person moved to a folder in my Documents folder.  I see in mail there is a place where I can use a .scpt in the rule.  But, I dont have the .scpt.  I have found the below, but I cannot find the savebyrule on my Mac....  Suggestions?  I dont know how to script !

Thanks for any help.

[image]